# Do my sentences flow natually

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> I finished 400+ hours of teaching assistant duty, including giving tutorials, delivering lectures, and supervising group projects. **This work was involved** in a total of four undergraduate courses, namely A, B, C, and D.

I want to demonstrate that I have done these types of work in four modules. The bolded words can be removed, forming one big sentence, but it will be too long (A, B, C, D are all long titles). So I split it, but am not sure if it reads naturally.

Comment: "Do my sentences flow naturally" would probably have been a better title, but I won't quibble about that! The rest do flow naturally. I don't think it would have been too long to remove the bolded words and collapse into one sentence. Either way, they flow quite well.

Comment: The only change I would personally suggest is the following. *This involved a total of …* The only reason I suggest this is that you never mention *work* in the first sentence. Even though it's implied, my first instinct on reading it was to ask, "What work?" But simply using a nonspecific *this* means I understand it's talking about everything in the first sentence. (Also, to me, a simple *involved* sounds better than *was involved in*.)